# lighttpd mod_rewrite to remote URLs for certain file extentions

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I am trying to set up a local development lighttpd server with all the PHP, HTML and CSS files of my project. I want to set up lighttpd to load these files locally, but for any other file extension, load remotely on a remote website via a URL.

I have tried the following code in the lighttpd.conf file:

```
url.rewrite =  (  "^(.*)$" => "http://<remote site>/"  )
```

and I have also tried

```
url.rewrite =  (  "^(.*)$" => "http://<remote site>/$1"  )
```

This was a test for redirecting everything, however both of these return a 404 for any URL I try, so something is wrong already and is stopping me going any further.

Can someone give me some help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the option you're looking for is redirects via [mod_redirect](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modredirect) written as `url.redirect`.

This will tell the browser to go to the new url for the resource. This does slow things down slightly as the browser has to make a second request to go to the actual location of the resource.